# How to prevent Safari from implicitly converting character in XHR request?

Tags: unicode, safari, character-encoding, string

I picked this character `〉` as a separator for my combo-key-field for my DynamoDb database.

That character surfaces in the browser as part of a next-page-query token. (in an endless scroll list view)

Chrome properly sends that character to the backend (as part of the next-page-query token).

However, Safari, sends that character as this character: `〉`, which is different, and as a result, my backend is unable to recognise it.

Why is the browser changing the character? Is this behaviour expected? Did I miss declaring a char-set somewhere?

Probably an important finding is that running `'〉' === '〉'` returns `true` in Safari.

wAt?

Answer (score 0):

When working with Chrome or any browser, do not use the
[HTML Reserved Characters](https://www.html.am/reference/html-special-characters.cfm):

[image]

Within a URL, you could use instead the hex notation, which for `>` is `%62`,
or the HTML-entity notation, which is `&gt;`.
But this probably does not relate to your case.

I suggest to use another character which is not in the above list.

Comment: There is no guarantee that I'll not pick a wrong one again. We need to understand why is the one I picked, the wrong one.

Comment: Only characters from the above list are reserved.

Comment: I got that. But that means that my character is not reserved, and yet, the problem is there.

Comment: Your character is the `gt`, which is reserved.

Comment: Oh, I see the confusion. No, it's not `gt`. It's a different one.  I deliberately chose a character that is not on the keyboard.

Comment: If it's non-ASCII, then these are not reserved, but they pass badly. You should then use the above hex encoding.